# Returning property on box unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, properties

Trying to return form controls property to "enabled" if a checkbox is unchecked.
So, for this HTML piece:

```
<div id="post">
    <div class="Response">
        <label><input type="radio" name="Radio402" value="Y" id="R402Y" onchange='radioChange(this, "402")'>Yes</label>
    </div>

    <div class="responseDetails">
        <div class="Observation">
            <label for="Obs402">Observation:</label>
            <textarea name="observation" id="Obs402" rows="6" disabled></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="DueDate">
            <label for="DueDate402">Due date:<br></label>
            <input name="DueDate" class="DueDate_in" type="text" id="DueDate402"/>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <label for="pa402">Actions required to correct and/or prevent this observation:</label>
            <textarea name="actions" id="pa402" rows="6"></textarea>
        </div>?
    </div>
</div>

<label for="item">Check me</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="item"/>
```

I am applying this JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if($("#item").click(function()
    {
        $("#post").prop("disabled", true);
    }));
    else
    {
        $("#post").prop("disabled", false);
    };
});
```

also tried that

```
$("#item").change(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#post").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $("#post").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

It gets disabled if CHECKED, but if UNCHECKED it REMAINS disabled. What am I doing wrong? I also tried `change(function)()`. I got the feeling that JS does not see unchecking event and therefore does not return the property. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Oh guys, forgott to mention, there is textarea element that by default stays DISABLED and is controlled by a radiobtn elsewhere. This textfield shall NOT get ENABLED when box is unchecked.

Comment: first js snippet won't work anyway, I believe, because you are checking the moment the document is loaded if #item is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `:checked`

```
$('#item').on('click', function(){
    $("#post").prop("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VTtw5/

Comment: The .toggle() function in jQuery is for animation. Or is that not what you mean?

Comment: actually I figured it out straingt after asking. I wanted to hide after disabling, so I just added .toggle(). Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ah gotcha. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the condition checking whether the check box is checked or not inside the change handler(prefer change event to click event) of the element. Then you need to enable/disable the input elements inside the `#post` element

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //change event handler
    $("#item").change(function () {
        //disable/enable input elements
        $("#post :input").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
    }).change();//set the initial state based on checked state of the checkbox
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JetJ8/)

Comment: thanks. Your function makes all elements DISABLED by default, whereas they are ENABLED by default apart from one textarea (see html code above).

Comment: @Alexander I'm setting the default state based on the checked state